# Is there a way to regenerate JPA entities once table is changed

Tags: jpa, wid

I have created some JPA entities, and the table structure has changed a bit since I first recreated them.  Is there a way to regenerate the tables so I don't lose any of the relationships or named queries that I have created?  I really don't want to lose those.  I am using Web Interface Developer btw... Which is just IBM's eclipse.

Comment: Guess not.  I had to rebuild the enitre JPA entity by hand.  Which was a real pain in the rear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net Beans IDE has a useful generate entities from database tables. You just have to select "update" from the drop down menu in the wizard as opposed to the "new" option. I realize that you are not using Net Beans but this could potentially be useful to someone else looking for the same functionality.

Comment: Since you out that caveout in there I marked your answer up.  But it is not an answer.  I suppose the true answer is, that no such functionality exists.